# Range of a heading angle [0,2π) or [−π,π)

Tags: mobile-robot, kinematics, dynamics, coordinate-system

Consider the unicycle dynamics in 2D plane:

[image]

$$\begin{array}{l}
\dot x = v\cos \varphi \\
\dot y = v\sin \varphi \\
\dot \varphi  = \omega 
\end{array}$$

What is the range of the heading angle $\phi$? Some texts say $\varphi  \in [ - \pi ,\pi ) $ and other use this convention $\varphi  \in [ 0 ,2\pi ) $. What is the reason for this difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No difference at all although φ∈[−π,π) is much more reasonable and intuitive. It is just a matter of system definition.